# Circuit Analysis problem (find the problem)

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, physics, laplace-transform, mathematical-physics

In this question, I know that $\text{C},\text{R},\text{T},\text{A}\in\mathbb{R}^+$

I've this circuit (the bottom of the resitor is connected to earth ($0$)):
[image]

When I use Laplace transform I can find that:

- $$\text{V}_{\text{out}}(s)=\frac{\text{R}}{\text{R}+\frac{1}{\text{C}s}}\cdot\text{V}_{\text{in}}(s)$$

My input function $\text{V}_{\text{in}}(t)$ is:

[image]

When I use Laplace transform, I can find that:

- $$\text{V}_{\text{in}}(s)=\frac{\text{A}\tanh\left(\frac{\text{T}s}{4}\right)}{s}$$

Now, when I substitute that in, I get that:

- $$\text{V}_{\text{out}}(s)=\frac{\text{R}}{\text{R}+\frac{1}{\text{C}s}}\cdot\frac{\text{A}\tanh\left(\frac{\text{T}s}{4}\right)}{s}$$

So, when I solved the inverse Laplace transform. I got ($\text{H}(x)$ is the Heaviside stepfunction):

- $$\text{V}_{\text{out}}(t)=\text{A}\exp\left[-\frac{t}{\text{CR}}\right]-2\text{A}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\text{H}\left(t-\frac{\text{T}n}{2}\right)\exp\left[-\frac{\left(t-\frac{\text{T}n}{2}\right)}{\text{CR}}\right]$$

Now, when I choose values $\text{T}=\frac{1}{50},\text{R}=1980,\text{A}=6,\text{C}=\frac{47\times10^{-6}}{10}$

I got a graph that looks like:

[image]

> Q: When I build it I looked at the scope and that told me that the graph I should get looks somehing like the picture down here, where is my mistake?:

[image]

I noticed, when I took out the floor part of my $\text{V}_{\text{out}}(t)$ function (I get that with mathematica) and set $\text{A}=-6$ I got a graph that look more like the thing I expected, but here I dont understand why it oscillates around $18$, it should me around $0$:
[image]

Comment: Given the scale, your last graph looks like it is caused by floating point error rather than real oscillation. Anyway, I am a bit skeptical all the way back at your Laplace transform step; it seems to me that your circuit is pure RC, so at a point after the capacitor the voltage should be tending towards zero (provided the frequency of your input divided by RC is sufficiently small). What happens when you measure at the other two possible points? (One should give zero, one should give $V_{in}$, but you should check that.)

Comment: The frequency is $50$ Hz in my circuit. At the output I get the graph that I sketched up in my question

Comment: I know what you get where you said you measured, I was asking about the other two points. I'm basically asking for a consistency check, that you get the measurements that you should get at the other two points (which are $V_{in}$ and $0$ respectively).

Comment: Yes, I get because $0$ is ground so I see noting on my scope and when I look at the input I see that square wave as expected ofcourse, because that's my input

Comment: OK. In that case I think you should double check your original Laplace transform calculation.

Comment: @Ian I got it from here http://www.secs.oakland.edu/~frick/ECE276_W11_ICN/Laplace_Notes.pdf at page 86

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transfer function is 
$$
H(s)=\frac{V_{\text{out}}(s)}{V_{\text{in}}(s)}=\frac{s}{s+\frac{1}{\tau}}
$$
where $\tau=RC$. The input voltage is
$$
V_{\text{in}}(s)=\frac{A}{s}\tanh\left(\frac{sT}{4}\right)=\frac{A}{s}\left(1-\mathrm e^{-\frac{Ts}{2}}\right)^2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \mathrm e^{-kTs}
$$
and then
$$
V_{\text{out}}(s)=\frac{A}{s+\frac{1}{\tau}}\left(1-2\mathrm e^{-\frac{Ts}{2}}+\mathrm e^{-Ts}\right)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \mathrm e^{-kTs}=F(s)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \mathrm e^{-kTs}
$$
The inverse Laplace transform gives
$$
v_{\text{out}}(t)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} f(t-kT)
$$
where
$$
f(t)=A\left[\mathrm e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}} u\left(t\right)-
2\mathrm e^{-\frac{1}{\tau}\left(t-\frac{T}{2}\right)} u\left(t-\tfrac{T}{2}\right)+\mathrm e^{-\frac{1}{\tau}\left(t-T\right)} u\left(t-T\right)
\right]
$$
and $u(t)$ is the Heaviside function.

Check [here](http://www4b.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot[6+e%5E%28-1.07458+t%29+%281.0666+theta%28t-3%2F50%29-2.1104+theta%28t-1%2F20%29%2B2.08784+theta%28t-1%2F25%29-2.06553+theta%28t-3%2F100%29%2B2.04345+theta%28t-1%2F50%29-2.02161+theta%28t-1%2F100%29%2Btheta%28t%29%29,%7Bt,0,4%2F50%7D]) for the first 3 periods with your values.

If for simplicity we put $\tau=2$ and $T=1$ we have the plot [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E%7B10%7D+6%28e%5E%28-%28%28t-kT%29%2Ftau%29%29+theta%28%28t-kT%29%29+-+2+e%5E%28-%281%2Ftau%29%28%28t-kT%29-T%2F2%29%29+theta%28%28t-kT%29-T%2F2%29%2Be%5E%28-%281%2Ftau%29%28%28t-kT%29-T%29%29+theta%28%28t-kT%29-T%29%29+where+tau%3D2+and+T%3D1)

Comment: I think you mean $\text{v}_{\text{out}}(t)$ and in the bottom equation $f(t)$ I've to set $t=t-kT$?

Comment: What function should I plot to get the right graph?

Comment: Do I've to plot this:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}A\left[\mathrm e^{-\frac{t-kT}{\tau}} u\left(t-kT\right)-
2\mathrm e^{-\frac{1}{\tau}\left(t-kT-\frac{T}{2}\right)} u\left(t-kT-\tfrac{T}{2}\right)+\mathrm e^{-\frac{1}{\tau}\left(t-kT-T\right)} u\left(t-kT-T\right)
\right]$$

Comment: yes the last one that is $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}f(t-kT)$

Comment: What you mean by last one?

Comment: you have to plot  $v_{\text{out}}(t)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}f(t-kT)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}A\left[\mathrm e^{-\frac{t-kT}{\tau}} u\left(t-kT\right)- 2\mathrm e^{-\frac{1}{\tau}\left(t-kT-\frac{T}{2}\right)} u\left(t-kT-\tfrac{T}{2}\right)+\mathrm e^{-\frac{1}{\tau}\left(t-kT-T\right)} u\left(t-kT-T\right) \right]$

Comment: the minus before the $2$? is related the negative part of the square wave.

Comment: Thanks for your help for now. Where was the mistake in my work?

Comment: in the inverse Laplace transform. I don't know how you've calculated it...

Comment: Your first link to a plot, I can not open it. But is it the graph that I expected (see the handwritten graph in my question)?

Comment: yes it has the same shape. But at $t=kT/2$ you cannot have the null value. the shape is like [this](http://www5b.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP22401gd0hag13067520f000051a9i13g4ab93cec?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=38) for $\tau=1$ and $T=15$

Comment: Ok, Nice. Why is that?

Comment: Because you have an exponential function with alternating sign shifted to have a periodic function. And an exponential function will be 0 at infinity, and of course $\neq 0$ for $kT/2$.

Comment: Oh yes, sure that's true.

Comment: you have something like [this](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/filter/fil39.gif?81223b) depending on the values of $\tau$, $T$ and $A$.

Comment: I've made another question to solve the inverse laplace transform. I want to prove your result. Maybe you can help: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1785157/finding-the-inverse-laplace-transform-of-this-function

Answer (score 0):

Your circuit is a passive differentiator I think. There is one zero and one pole and the operation of the differentiation on the square wave (hence the spikes to be expected as your picture shows) occurs at frequencies below the pole frequency. You should be getting a Dirac delta function in the output for this, I think, after taking the inverse transform.