# Finding the inverse Laplace transform of this function

Tags: inverse, laplace-transform

Find the inverse Laplace transform of this function ([related to my question earlier](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1784912/circuit-analysis-problem-find-the-problem#1785025)):

$$f(t)=\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{s}{s+\frac{1}{\tau}}\cdot\frac{A}{s}\left(1-\mathrm e^{-\frac{Ts}{2}}\right)^2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\mathrm e^{-nTs}\right]_{(s)}$$

I'm not sure how to go.

For $t>0$ we can find that:

$$f(t)=\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{s}{s+\frac{1}{\tau}}\cdot\frac{A\tanh\left(\frac{Ts}{4}\right)}{s}\right]_{(s)}=A\left(e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}}-2\tau\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{\left(1+e^{\frac{Ts}{2}}\right)\left(1+\tau s\right)}\right]_{(s)}\right)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your related question we have $F(s)=H(s)\cdot G(s)=\frac{s}{s+\frac{1}{\tau}}\cdot\frac{A}{s}\tanh\left(\frac{sT}{4}\right)$
and then
\begin{align}
\color{blue}{F(s)}&=\frac{A}{s+\frac{1}{\tau}}\cdot\tanh\left(\frac{sT}{4}\right)
=\frac{A}{s+\frac{1}{\tau}}\cdot\frac{\mathrm e^{\frac{Ts}{4}}-\mathrm e^{-\frac{Ts}{4}}}{\mathrm e^{\frac{Ts}{4}}+\mathrm e^{-\frac{Ts}{4}}}=\frac{A}{s+\frac{1}{\tau}}\cdot\frac{1-\mathrm e^{-\frac{Ts}{2}}}{1+\mathrm e^{-\frac{Ts}{2}}}\\
&\color{blue}{=\frac{A}{s+\frac{1}{\tau}}\cdot\left(1-\mathrm e^{-\frac{Ts}{2}}\right)^2\cdot\frac{1}{1-\mathrm e^{-sT}}}\\
&=\frac{A}{s+\frac{1}{\tau}}\cdot\left(1-\mathrm e^{-\frac{Ts}{2}}\right)^2\cdot\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \mathrm e^{-nTs}\\
&=\frac{A}{s+\frac{1}{\tau}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(1-\mathrm e^{-\frac{Ts}{2}}\right)^2\mathrm e^{-nTs}\\
&=\frac{A}{s+\frac{1}{\tau}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left[\mathrm e^{-nTs}-2\mathrm e^{-\frac{2n+1}{2}Ts}+\mathrm e^{-(n+1)Ts}\right]\\
&=A\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{s+\frac{1}{\tau}}\left[\mathrm e^{-nTs}-2\mathrm e^{-\frac{2n+1}{2}Ts}+\mathrm e^{-(n+1)Ts}\right]\\
\end{align}
Observing that 
$$
\mathcal L^{-1}\left\{\frac{1}{s+a}\mathrm e^{-bs}\right\}=\mathrm e^{-a(t-b)}u(t-b)\tag{$\star$}
$$
we have
\begin{align}
\mathcal L^{-1}\left\{F(s)\right\}=f(t)&=A\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left[\mathrm e^{-\frac{1}{\tau}\left(t-nT\right)} u\left(t-nT\right)- 2\mathrm e^{-\frac{1}{\tau}\left(t-\frac{2n+1}{2}T\right)} u\left(t-\tfrac{2n+1}{2}T\right)+\right.\\
&\qquad\quad\left.+\mathrm e^{-\frac{1}{\tau}\left(t-(n+1)T\right)} u\left(t-(n+1)T\right) \right]
\end{align}

**Another way** is the following. Observe that if $$f(t)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f_0(t-nT)$$ we have $$\mathcal L\{f(t)\}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\mathcal L\{f_0(t-nT)\}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}F_0(s)\mathrm e^{-nTs}=F_0(s)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\mathrm e^{-nTs}=\frac{F_0(s)}{1-\mathrm e^{-Ts}}$$
So for your function we have 
$$
F(s)=\underbrace{\frac{A}{s+\frac{1}{\tau}}\cdot\left(1-\mathrm e^{-\frac{Ts}{2}}\right)^2}_{F_0(s)}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\mathrm e^{-sT}}
$$
that is 
$$
F_0(s)=\frac{A}{s+\frac{1}{\tau}}\cdot\left(1-2\mathrm e^{-\frac{Ts}{2}}+\mathrm e^{-{Ts}}\right)
$$
and then using $(\star)$ we have
$$
f_0(t)=A\left[\mathrm e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}} u\left(t\right)-
2\mathrm e^{-\frac{1}{\tau}\left(t-\frac{T}{2}\right)} u\left(t-\tfrac{T}{2}\right)+\mathrm e^{-\frac{1}{\tau}\left(t-T\right)} u\left(t-T\right)
\right]
$$
and finally
\begin{align}
f(t)&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f_0(t-nT)\\
&=A\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left[\mathrm e^{-\frac{1}{\tau}\left(t-nT\right)} u\left(t-nT\right)- 2\mathrm e^{-\frac{1}{\tau}\left(t-\frac{2n+1}{2}T\right)} u\left(t-\tfrac{2n+1}{2}T\right)+\right.\\
&\qquad\quad\left.+\mathrm e^{-\frac{1}{\tau}\left(t-(n+1)T\right)} u\left(t-(n+1)T\right) \right]
\end{align}

**A third way** starting with your work
$$f(t)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{k\left(\frac{1}{s+\frac{1}{\tau}}\right)\left(1-\frac{2}{\mathrm e^{\frac{T}{2}s}+1}\right)\right\} = A\,\mathrm e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}} - 2A\tau \, \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{1}{\left(1+\mathrm e^{\frac{T}{2}s}\right)\left(1+\tau s\right)}\right\}$$
then, observing that $$\frac{1}{1+\mathrm e^{\frac{T}{2}s}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}\mathrm e^{-\frac{T}{2} (n+1) s}$$
we have
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{1}{\left(1+\mathrm e^{\frac{T}{2}s}\right)\left(1+\tau s\right)}\right\} &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} \, \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{\mathrm e^{-\frac{T}{2} (n+1) s}}{1+\tau s}\right\} \\
&= \frac{1}{\tau} \, \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} \, u\left(t - (n+1) \frac{T}{2}\right) \, \mathrm e^{- \frac{1}{\tau}\left(t - \frac{T}{2} (n+1)\right)}
\end{align}
which leads to
$$f(t)= A\left[\mathrm e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}} - 2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} \, u\left(t - (n+1) \frac{T}{2}\right) \, \mathrm e^{- \frac{1}{\tau}\left(t - \frac{T}{2} (n+1)\right)}\right]$$

Comment: Thank you, very much! You're a great help